# Change a string in xml into an array in xml easily

Tags: arrays, string, xslt, format

I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a simple way to change all of my strings in my xml file to arrays?

Example:

```
//This is the string I need to change:
<string name="sample1">value1, value2, value3, value4, value5</string>
//This is the way I need it to be:
<array name="sample1">
    <item>value1</item>
    <item>value2</item>
    <item>value3</item>
    <item>value4</item>
    <item>value5</item>
</array>
```

My problem is not that I do not know how to manually do it. But I am looking for a way to simulate this process more easily because I have 120 strings with 25-90 values in each.

A good example would be converting multiple images extentions with a single click using an add-on to GIMP that simulates that process for you for each image.

Would anyone who understands what I am asking, know a way to do this for string to array?

Comment: you could use XSLT since you are dealing with XML

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT. I can give you a transformation in xslt in about an hour if you want to give it a try

Comment: I would like that if its not too much trouble.  I read up on that and it sounds like what i need, but i couldn't see where it can convert the string into an array.

Comment: @peter can we convert an XML to another XML using XSLT?

Comment: @aravind: yes, you use XSLT to convert XML to XML, HTML or Text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <array>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="string/@name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </array>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="string/text()" name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="sep" select="','"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $sep))">
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/>
            </item>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <item>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $sep))"/>
            </item>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $sep)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string name="sample1">value1, value2, value3, value4, value5</string>
```

gives this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<array name="sample1">
<item>value1</item>
<item>value2</item>
<item>value3</item>
<item>value4</item>
<item>value5</item>
</array>
```

The XSLT is using a recursive template going through your string values and splitting them at the comma.

Comment: Nice answer. But be careful when normalizing the string values, maybe there are whitespaces allowed within the data.

Comment: Okay so i ran the xsl transformation using what you have supplied, and I get an Error:  res\layout\NewStylesheet.xsl: **No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/MyName/Documents/My Dropbox/Personal/workspace/MySampleApp/res/values/strings.xml**

Comment: hi zack2o, in the source xml before <string...> place this line: <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?> and in href give your file name. regards, peter

Comment: okay i did that and i get this error now:  
17:39:13,667 **ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(tokenize, [step("self", -1), literal-expr(,\s*)])'.**
17:39:13,669 ERROR [main] **JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Could not compile stylesheet**

Comment: Was functioning properly, but now after i run it, nothing happens.  No new strings.out.xml or even any errors.  Any idea why it all of a suddden has stopped doing anything?

Comment: Fixed it, this is now working as intended and thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hi zack2o, sorry I could not answer anymore, it was already night for me. Glad you got it running. All the best with your new knowledge! Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 1):

**This can be done with XSLT 2.0 as simply as**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <array name="{@name}">
     <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',\s*')">
      <item><xsl:value-of select="."/></item>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </array>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<string name="sample1">value1, value2, value3, value4, value5</string>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<array name="sample1">
   <item>value1</item>
   <item>value2</item>
   <item>value3</item>
   <item>value4</item>
   <item>value5</item>
</array>
```

Comment: seems like the same error for both, am i missing something:   
**No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/Users/MyName/Documents/My Dropbox/Personal/workspace/MySampleApp/res/values/strings.xml**

Comment: It seems that you are trying to run the transformation in some weird way. A transformation needs to be in its own file -- not embedded in the XML file that is to be transformed.